# Non HTML5 Placeholder Directive that works with ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have come across a problem my Angular knowledge is a little too limited to figure out. I want a non html5 placeholder attribute. Here is some code I found before on stack overflow that does this handsomely:

```
// Placeholder for non HTML5 browsers
app.directive("ngPlaceholder", function($log, $timeout) {
    var txt;
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: { txt: "@ngPlaceholder" },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            elem.on("focus", function() {
                if(elem.val() === scope.txt) {
                    elem.val("");
                }
                scope.$apply()
            })

            elem.on("blur", function() {
                if(elem.val() === "") {
                    elem.val(scope.txt);
                }
                scope.$apply()
            })

            // Initialise placeholder
            $timeout(function() {
                elem.val(scope.txt)
                scope.$apply();
            })
        }
    }
})
```

However... use it in conjunction with ng-model:

```
input(
  type="text"
  ng-model="card.number"
  ng-placeholder="0000-0000-0000-0000")
```

And it obliterates the two way data binding!

Heres a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/1AvVOxb5O6P5pU3wIuKv?p=preview

What am I missing?

**Update** Many people have voiced there solutions to this rather annoying problem [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1924)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $parent to refer the to model in the parent scope since the directive ngPlaceholder creates an isolated scope. (This is not specific to IE 9 though. )

```
<input type="text" ng-placeholder="0000-0000-0000-0000" ng-model="$parent.card.number2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess the bigger question is how are different scopes chained together for multiple directives on the same element (and what is the scope definition of ng-model)

Comment: This directive doesn't need its own scope. If you remove the scope property from the directive definition, it works as expected. http://plnkr.co/edit/CI5V2d4r7ajN9MCH3I8H?p=preview

Comment: Yes I am aware of that :). It feels like a workaround though. IMO adding a directive with "isolate" scope to a DOM element shouldn't affect the use of other directives on that element. Just came across a similar thread with many disgruntled users: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1924

Answer (score 2):

This one fixes the problem that in delay of $timeout, the $scope may be changed in meantime. It also makes it cross-browser.

```
// Placeholder for all browsers
app.directive("ngPlaceholder", function($log, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var txt = attrs.ngPlaceholder,
                model = attrs.ngModel,
                placeholderSupport = 'placeholder' in document.createElement("input");

            //Use HTML5 placeholder attribute.
            if (placeholderSupport) {
                attrs.$set("placeholder", txt);
                return;
            }

            elem.on("focus", function(event) {
                if (elem.val() === txt) {
                    elem.val("");
                }
            });

            elem.on("blur", function(event) {
                if (elem.val() === "") {
                    elem.val(txt);
                }
            });

            scope.$watch(model, function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                if (newValue === undefined || newValue === "") {
                    elem.val(txt);
                    //scope.$apply(); not needed, since scope fired this event.
                }
            }, true);
        }
    }
```

});

Comment: I vote up for you answer because of the HTML5 use, but this solution doesn't support the form validation system that is built in angular. You can turn this answer valid by complementing its structure with this one (which doesn't cover the HTML5 support): https://gist.github.com/EpokK/5884029

Answer (score 1):

You seen the ngModel issue, so the isolate scope on ngPlaceholder should be removed. I realize that sza's workaround works, but the key thing I'd emphasize is that the ngPlaceholder doesn't need its own scope.

For example here I tweaked the directive and removed the references to scope by storing creating the txt variable as its own local variable.
http://plnkr.co/edit/43z1TZHFwmgLJ9wyystD?p=preview

```
// Placeholder for non HTML5 browsers
app.directive("ngPlaceholder", function($log, $timeout) {
    var txt;
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var txt = attrs.ngPlaceholder;

            elem.bind("focus", function() {
                if(elem.val() === txt) {
                    elem.val("");
                }
                scope.$apply()
            })

            elem.bind("blur", function() {
                if(elem.val() === "") {
                    elem.val(txt);
                }
                scope.$apply()
            })

            // Initialise placeholder
            $timeout(function() {
                elem.val(txt)
                scope.$apply();
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes - it seems this is the best solution for the time being. This "bug" just kinda walked up and kicked me in the teeth. Still... Angular is relatively young and I believe this will be fixed soon(judging by the git-hub activity). It does make isolate scope verrrry unattractive for the time being though

Comment: Nice code. I used this, but had to do a small fix. The $timeout has a delay. In meantime, the scope was already changed on my side. I replaced $timeout part by a $watch part.

Answer (score 0):

**placeholder support in IE with normal color**

```
app.directive('placeholder',['$timeout','$window', function($timeout,$window){
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    if ('placeholder' in i) {
        return {}
    }
    return {
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            var userAgent = $window.navigator.userAgent;
            if(userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 9.0") <0){
                  return;
            } 
            if (attrs.type === 'password') {
                return;
            }
            $timeout(function(){
                elm.val(attrs.placeholder).css({"color":'#ccc'});
                elm.bind('focus', function(){
                    if (elm.val() == attrs.placeholder) {
                        elm.val('').css({"color":'#555'});
                    }
                }).bind('blur', function(){
                    if (elm.val() == '') {                      
                        elm.val(attrs.placeholder).css({"color":'#ccc'});
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

live code here:http://plnkr.co/edit/ev6kQ3Ks31FhqAfCMDkc